# Add not managed applications to Chocolatey

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

Is it possible to add applications not managed by Chocolatey to Chocolatey?

When I run `choco list -li` I will get a list of installed apps ending with "47 applications not managed with Chocolatey".

How can I make them managed with Chocolatey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask for is indeed possible with Chocolatey, yet unfortunately **only with a licensed edition**.

See [Chocolatey Synchronize Feature](https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-synchronize).

With a 'Pro' or 'Architect' license you'll be able to list all programs of Programs & Features in Chocolatey and therefore receive upgrades for those if available in any of your configured Chocolatey sources.

With a 'Business (C4B)' license you'll even be able to do the other way round - have all your Chocolatey packages listed in Programs & Features.
See [Compare Chocoaltey Editions](https://chocolatey.org/compare) for more details.

hope that helps,